# Memory loss in following code when the CPU is 32 bit processor

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function to convert integer to string .The function is

```
char * Int_String(int Number)
{
    char* result;
    NAT   size = 1;

    if (Number > 9) {
        size = (NAT)log10((double) Number) + 1;
    } else if (Number < 0) {
        size = (NAT)log10((double) abs(Number)) + 2; /* including '-' */
    }
    size++; /* for '\0' */

    result = (char *) memory_Malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    sprintf(result, "%d", Number);
    return result;
}
```

`NAT` is `typedef unsigned int`

`Number` is  `int`

I am using this function in the following manner

```
char *s2;
char **Connections;
Connections = memory_Malloc(nc*sizeof(char*));
char con[]="c_";
k1=1;
for (i=0; i<nc ; i++){
    s2 = Int_ToString(k1);
    Connections[i]= string_Conc(con,s2);  
    string_StringFree(s2);     
    k1= k1+1;
}
```

And the functions`char* string_Conc(const char *s1, const char *S2)` is

```
{ 
    char* dst;

    dst = memory_Malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);
    strcpy(dst, s1);
    return strcat(dst,s2);
}
```

I am using following  methods to free its memory:

```
for(i=0; i<nc; i++){
    memory_Free(Connections[i],sizeof(char));
}
memory_Free(Connections,nc*sizeof(char*));
```

The problem that i am getting is: i can free all the allocated memory when `nc<=9`.But when it is `>=10` leakes memory in the multiple of 4 bytes with each increase in number. How can I remove the problem.Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT

```
  void memory_Free(POINTER Freepointer, unsigned int Size)
```

Thanks,
thetna

Comment: How can you tell whether it's leaking or not?

Comment: when i change the number of nc , then it gets change accordingly.If nc is 10, then 4 byte and if nc is 11 , then 8 bytes and so on.

Comment: @thetna, but where do you get the referred number of bytes from?

Comment: @thetna How are you observing the leakage? Valgrind? Top?

Comment: The same tool has some memory checking functions, which shows the leaked memory. I am sorry that i forget to mention it before, i tried with valgrind too, it is not showing any leak. The only difference in memory leak observe is taking different values of nc.

Comment: Unfortunately the tool has the function which can't show the location of memory leak. It  just prints the memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the implementation of `memory_Free` (neither `memory_Malloc`), so we don't know why you need to pass the supposed size of the memory block to be freed as a 2nd parameter (the standard `free()` doesn't need this). However, here

```
memory_Free(Connections[i],sizeof(char));
```

it is certainly wrong: `sizeof(char)` is 1 <strike>on most platforms</strike>, but the size of the allocated block is at least 4 bytes for each string in the array (as the strings contain "c_" plus at least one digit plus the terminating '\0').

#### Update

Looking through the source code you linked, this indeed seems to be the cause of your problem! The code inside `memory_Free` seems to align memory block sizes - I can assume that to 4-byte boundaries, which is very common. In this case, if the passed `Size` is 1, it happens to be corrected to 4 - exactly the right value in case of single digit numbers as shown above! However, numbers greater than 9 are converted to (at least) two digits, thus the size of the converted string is already 5. A block of 5 bytes is most probably allocated as an aligned block of 8 bytes under the hood - but since `memory_Free` is always called with a `Size` of 1, it always frees only 4 bytes. This leaves 4 bytes leaking per each number above 9, precisely as you described in your comment above!

To fix this, you need to modify the line above to

```
memory_Free(Connections[i], strlen(Connections[i]) + 1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP needs the size parameter though; the C `free()` certainly doesn't.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @thetna Ok, so why is there a size parameter?

Comment: @Fred, good catch, fixed. I must have mixed it up with the size in bytes which is not stardadized AFAIK.

Comment: i mean to say the functioning of memory_Free is same to Free() but it takes two functional arugements.I have added the definition of memory_Free().

Comment: @Péter Török: From the C++03 draft standard, "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand." (5.3.3)  "A byte is at least large enough to contain any
member of the basic execution character set and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is
composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined." (1.7)

Comment: @Fred, this is a C question though. And I apparently meant "the size of byte", not "the size in bytes" :-)

Comment: @thetna, that is only the function *declaration* - the *definition* is its *implementation*, including the code inside the function body. Can we have that please? :-)

Comment: @Péter Török: Oh, I missed that. I think the answer is the same for C, but I can't cite a reference.

Comment: @thetna, I think I have an explanation - see my update above.

Comment: @thetna With that definition, you have to call `memory_Free(Connections[i],strlen(Connections[i]) +1); not memory_Free(Connections[i],sizeof(char)); . Possibly you could just use the string_StringFree() function - though we don't really know - you apparently have a huge custom memory allocator that we don't know about - but you'll have to make *very* sure your're using that allocator correctly - hopefully it comes with good documentation.